# linq with Include and many-to-many

Tags: linq, include, many-to-many, iqueryable

I have rather specific requirement for my Linq statement. I've looked through dozens of examples, but could't find satisfying answer.

I have a collection of courses, which holds collection of groups, which holds collection of members. My goal is to create linq statement for IQuerable which returns a collection of courses that user belongs to, and includes collection of groups within each course that user belongs to if there is any.

I did manage to build a linq statement which returns what I wanted but filters out all of the courses that don't have any groups that user belongs to inside them:

```
var courses2 = (from c in _set
                       from s in c.Students
                       where (s.UserName == userName)
                       from g in c.Groups
                       from m in g.Members
                       where (m.UserName == userName)
                       select c)
                       .Include(c => c.Groups)
                       .OrderBy(c => c.Title)
```

How could I change it to include those as well?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention its an entity set for Course (DbSet<T>)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `student` entity has a nav property to entity `Class` for class membership, and `Class` entities have a nav property `Groups` to the `Group` entity, which in turn have a nav property to `Students`:

```
// get the students to query against
var students = db.Students.Where( s => s.UserName == userName );

// get classes per group
var classesViaGroups = 
    students.SelectMany( s => s.Groups )
    .SelectMany( g => 
        g.Classes.Select( c => 
            new { GroupName = g.Name, ClassObj = g.Class } ) );

// get classes by the student entities alone
var classesViaStudents = 
    students.SelectMany( s => s.Classes )
    .Select( c => new { GroupName = null, ClassObj = c } );
```

You can then do what you will with `classesViaGroups` and `classesViaStudents` - combine them, build a lookup or dictionary by group or class, etc.

Comment: I don't get it. I have one student only, and effectively want to end up with a query producing list of courses with list of groups inside (eager loading)